# CSS media Issues

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make my css work so that when I have a certain width the height of my product boxes goes higher but with this code:-

```
@media screen and (max-width: 464px) and (min-width: 400px) {
    .product-block {        
        margin: 0px;    
        height: 500px;  
    } 
}   
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) and (min-width: 465px) {   
    .product-block {
        margin: 0px;    
        height: 600px;  
    }
} 
@media (min-width: 993px) {     
    .product-block .cart {      
        padding-top:0px;        
        padding-left: 48px;     
    }   
}
```

It seems ill have `@media screen and (max-width: 992px) and (min-width: 465px)` keep overiding `@media screen and (max-width: 464px) and (min-width: 400px)` so if I am using my screen at 400px width to 464px width no matter what width I am in between these numbers (400px - 464px) it does not use that CSS it instead uses `@media screen and (max-width: 992px) and (min-width: 465px)` CSS no matter what width of my screen I am on! It seems to not be changing when it hits its minimum width and max width.

Comment: are there any style defined outside of these media queries?

Comment: did you put in the html a line: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` ?

Comment: Banzay I am not sure what you mean and these are my only media queries for these pages im positive

Comment: The website page i am on is https://www.budmonkeyseeds.co.uk/Feminised-Cannabis-Seeds take a look and tell me what you think because the css seems right to me

Comment: it's working fine, you need to clear your browser cache maybe

Comment: yes, it's working correctly in your original page